# Self-referencing MySQL table in UPDATE-query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following scenario:

3 tables are involved, 'patient', 'users' and 'center'. They have the following attributes and relationships:

'patient':

- pid = primary key
- doc = foreign key to 'uid' of 'users'
- localid = set to '-1' by default

'users':

- uid = primary key
- cid = foreign key to 'cid' of 'center'

'center':

- cid = primary key

Patients aren't directly assigned to a center. Instead, they are assigned to a specific user, who in turn is assigned to one center.

The 'localid' of the patient is currently set to '-1' for all patients. I'm trying to come up with a SQL query which increments the 'localid' for all patients, but only within the center they are indirectly associated with through the user.

In essence, I want all patients to have a unique ID within their center, but it should start at 0 for each center.

This is the query I have tried, which I think is close to what I need:

```
UPDATE patient p1
SET p1.localid=(SELECT (max(p2.localid) +1)
                FROM patient p2
                WHERE (SELECT u1.cid
                       FROM users u1
                       WHERE u1.uid=p1.doc)=(SELECT u2.cid
                                             FROM users u2
                                             WHERE u2.uid=p2.doc));
```

This results in the sql error "You can't specify target table 'p1' for update in FROM clause" because 'p1' is referencing itself in the WHERE-clause.

I can easily solve this problem by using multiple SQL queries and a loop in PHP, but I was wondering if it was possible to solve this with just plain SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using subqueries, you can `JOIN` the table to itself using the criteria from your subquery and give it an alias. That should allow you to update the same table you're querying.

Something like...

```
UPDATE patient p1
SET p1.localid = p2.newlocalid
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT pid, MAX(localid) + 1 AS newlocalid
    FROM patient p2
    WHERE...
) p2 ON p1.pid = p2.pid
```